How to setup k8s Windows node using Calico Operator
I have now tried for a week to properly setup Windows k8s node using Calico without success. I have followed official Calico documentation docs.tigera.io. I have tried both Operator and Manual install without success. I am stuck in both cases at HPC operations as my Linux master cannot get Windows node into Ready status. Here are the steps:

My containers are in AWS EC2 where I have 1 master, 1 Linux node and 1 windows node. Security groups are properly setup and ports between master and nodes are open.
My Linux node is connecting with no issues (I have deployed pods on master and Linux node and they are operating as expected)
I have initiated my cluster with sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
After that I have followed Calico Operator install with updates to Pods to allow only VXLAN and strict affinity

This is what pods are looking like:
NAMESPACE          NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-apiserver   calico-apiserver-844c7896b7-8qr98         1/1     Running   0          86m
calico-apiserver   calico-apiserver-844c7896b7-hhsfn         1/1     Running   0          86m
calico-system      calico-kube-controllers-98fbc76fb-x6p88   1/1     Running   0          86m
calico-system      calico-node-4c2vp                         1/1     Running   0          86m
calico-system      calico-node-cbhld                         1/1     Running   0          86m
calico-system      calico-typha-7b579d4b66-96jm4             1/1     Running   0          86m
calico-system      calico-typha-7b579d4b66-k2lkb             1/1     Running   0          86m
calico-system      csi-node-driver-84jlq                     2/2     Running   0          112m
calico-system      csi-node-driver-l5nmb                     2/2     Running   0          112m
kube-system        coredns-7db6d8ff4d-2hbs9                  1/1     Running   0          114m
kube-system        coredns-7db6d8ff4d-vlvfg                  1/1     Running   0          114m
kube-system        etcd-ip-172-16-8-123                      1/1     Running   9          115m
kube-system        kube-apiserver-ip-172-16-8-123            1/1     Running   9          115m
kube-system        kube-controller-manager-ip-172-16-8-123   1/1     Running   2          115m
kube-system        kube-proxy-566rb                          1/1     Running   0          113m
kube-system        kube-proxy-fkvv2                          1/1     Running   0          114m
kube-system        kube-proxy-windows-j4fgh                  1/1     Running   0          83m
kube-system        kube-scheduler-ip-172-16-8-123            1/1     Running   9          115m
tigera-operator    tigera-operator-76ff79f7fd-tj5pp          1/1     Running   0          113m

Nodes:
NAME              STATUS     ROLES           AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION    CONTAINER-RUNTIME
ec2amaz-5bu9t2v   NotReady   <none>          90m    v1.30.0   172.16.8.235   <none>        Windows Server 2022 Datacenter   10.0.20348.2402   containerd://1.7.1
ip-172-16-8-123   Ready      control-plane   115m   v1.30.0   172.16.8.123   <none>        Ubuntu 24.04 LTS                 6.8.0-1008-aws    containerd://1.7.16
ip-172-16-8-26    Ready      <none>          114m   v1.30.0   172.16.8.26    <none>        Ubuntu 24.04 LTS                 6.8.0-1008-aws    containerd://1.7.16


I have setup Windows Server 2022 with instructions from the Calico docs. All is well until step 6: Install kube-proxy on Windows nodes (If kube-proxy is not running, you must install and run kube-proxy on each of the Windows nodes in your cluster). I was not sure what is meant there as I understood that using config is done with sig-windows-tools on master node.
I have downloaded sig-windows-tools and modified scripts to match my cluster. I have built all required images for calico and kube-proxy and uploaded to AWS registry.
Deployed with no issues.

Windows and Linux are running containerd.
Kubernetes: 1.30.0
Calico: 3.28.0
Describe from Node:
Ready            False   Tue, 21 May 2024 22:53:04 +0000   Tue, 21 May 2024 21:19:39 +0000   KubeletNotReady              container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cd

Describe from Win proxy:
k logs kube-proxy-windows-j4fgh -n kube-system
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'hns' include unapproved verbs that might make them less 
discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose 
parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
Running kub-proxy service.
Waiting for HNS network Calico to be created...

I am stuck now and do not understand how to proceed with making Windows node Ready. Any help is appreciated.

The issue you are facing here is still open: https://github.com/tigera/docs/issues/1547
Please, follow this manual. It worked for me.
